# Python: Counting "pairs" in two lists

Tags: python

I want to check if the items in two lists matches a certain criteria.

```
List1 = [4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2]
List2 = [3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4]
```

I want to output the number of pairs at the same indexes, that are either (1,2), (2,1), (4,3) or (3,4).

In this case, the program should output 3, since the values at index 0 is (4,3), index 2 is (3,4) and at index 3 is (1,2).

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: so (1,2),(2,1),(3,4),and (4,3) are the only matches?  (1,1), (2,3), etc. aren't?  Is there a definition of a "match" other than that arbitrary list?

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for:

```
>>> List1 = [4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2]
>>> List2 = [3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4]
>>> sum(1 for x in zip(List1, List2) if sorted(x) in ([1,2], [3,4]))
3
>>>
```

Comment: The above only counts matches at the same index, too, @SteinarLima.  zip() only pairs up items from the same position in the two lists - it's not a cartesian product or anything.

Comment: @SteinarLima - He said 1&2, 2&1, 3&4, and 4&3 are matches.  2&3 or 3&2 are not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
List1 = [4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2]
List2 = [3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4]

for i in range(len(List1)):
   if abs(List1[i] - List2[i]) == 1:
       print "its a match"
       print List1[i], List2[i]
```

Comment: This is closer, but this matches 2 and 3, which he didn't want.